# EF LINQ query with Contains returns not all matched records

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a `.NET Core 3.1` application with Entity Framework talking to PostgreSQL database.
I use `Npgsql` library 3.1.0, code-first pattern and LINQ to make queries.

So, I have a table `Meetings` with object like this:

```cs
public class Meeting
{
    [Key] 
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string CreatorId { get; set; }
    public List<string> Members { get; set; }
}
```

My query is:

```cs
var userId = "...";
using var db = new DatabaseContext();
var meetings = db.Meetings.Where(m => m.CreatorId == userId || m.Members.Contains(userId));
```

And it returns all records that matche first criteria: `m.CreatorId == userId`, but no records for the second: `m.Members.Contains(userId)`.

This also doesn't work:

```cs
var meetings = db.Meetings.Where(m => m.Members.Contains(userId));
```

Returns zero records. But there are definitely matching records, because this:

```cs
var meetings = db.Meetings.ToList().Where(m => m.Members.Contains(userId));
```

Returns several records as expected.

Why does it happen? How can I use `Contains` in query like this?

Comment: It might be that `.Contains` is translated into a case-sensitive SQL function in PostgreSQL, meaning that you are probably passing in a lower case guid and matching against uppercase guid's. Try to either fix it by doing ToUpper() on the userId or by swapping the .Contains for `EF.Functions.Like(m.Members, userId)`

Comment: try this one : var meetings = db.Meetings.Include(m=>m.Members).Where(m => m.Members.Contains(userId));

Comment: Is _Members_ a different table? did you include it in the context and set up the model?

Comment: @Dennis1679 it was my first hypothesis, but my ids are numeric strings, like "123"

Comment: @DanielSchmid no, Members is array field, Postgres supports them

Comment: @MehrdadDowlatabadi `InvalidOperationException Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I've figured it out myself.

According to the [documentation](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/array.html) `...Contains()` query should transform to `WHERE 3 = ANY(c."SomeArray")` SQL operator, but there is an annotaion below:

**Note that operation translation on List<> is limited at this time, but will be improved in the future. It's recommended to use an array for now.**

I changed my model to:

```cs
public class Meeting
{
    [Key] 
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string CreatorId { get; set; }
    public string[] Members { get; set; }
}
```

and now it works.